# How do I configure my web application for Binding with core service in Tridion 8.5 VERSION 9?

Tags: core-service, sdl-tridion

I am developing a ASP.NET (C#) web application that will run on a Content Manager server which will use Tridion 8.5 VERSION 9 core service.

I am building a simple web application which will use core service to get the component from tridion

Any sample project would be really appreciated

Comment: "Tridion 8.5 VERSION 9" is a confusing statement. There is SDL Web 8.5 or SDL Tridion Sites 9.0 / 9.1 (meaning the product was renamed in between 8.5 and 9.0). Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Best place to start is reading the documentation. It shows the steps needed to get started with your .NET app : https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-9575DB42-91DB-4AED-B2C0-BE97F27DB23C

Next, check some of the examples you can find here : https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/CookbookDocumentation

It contains various examples of working with core services.